# Activity Navigation Prevent when the internet is not available at splash

Tags: android, android-activity

I am using a global internet check connection. I am implementing a functionality like if network is not available in splash screen with Onresume method, then I am displaying a alert dialog for network unavailability. But i did not  stop the splash activity.

According to my source code when the internet is not available it give me a dialog but the splash activity move further and it is going to Login activity. I  dont want to navigate. I want to exit the splash after some moment with dialog.

please help me.

Comment: show your splash activity code.

Comment: @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        makeActivityFullScreen();
  //-----//---from here i am checking internet--//
  if(networkAvail){
   
   
  }else{
   dialog.show();
   finish();
   
  }
    }

Comment: can you log and check networkAvail state ?

Answer (score 0):

do like this and in alertdialog ok button presse put finish()

```
  @Override protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
    if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        Constt.showInternetDialog(this);
        return;
    }
    makeActivityFullScreen();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put finish() inside alert dialog button click. Try this

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Error");
    builder.setMessage("Network not available");
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
```